# Lock, process and release lock in jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, oracle11g, distributed-transactions

Thats my requirement - to lock a database record, process it and release it

Environment - weblogic 10.3
Database - Oracle 11g
Datasources - multiple XA recources involved
Tx mgr - JTA

Here are the results of the experiments I have done so far:

**Experiment 1 - Rely on read uncommitted**

1. Read the db record
2. Lock the record by id in another table, as part of the global JTA transaction
3. Process the record
   A second transaction which tries to lock the same record will fail, will drop the record.
   But for this to work the RDBMS should allow dirty reads.
   Unfortunately Oracle does not support read uncommitted isolation level.

**Experiment 2 - Lock record in local transaction**

1. Read the db record
2. Lock the record by id in another table, as a separate local transaction
3. Process the record and delete the record when the transaction commits successfully
   A second transaction which tries to lock the same record will fail, will drop the record. This approach is based on committed data, should work fine.
   Here is the problem - Since the lock transaction and the global parent are different, if the processing fails rolling back the main transaction, I should compensate by rolling back the lock transaction, which I do not know how to do - **Need help here**

If Iam not able to rollback the record locking transaction, would have to write some dirty logic around the record locking code. I dont prefer this.

This appears to be a very common requirement. I would like to know how you guys handle this elegantly.
Does Oracle support in any way making uncommitted updates visible to all transactions.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: In experiment what should happen is the following: get db record, lock the record by id in another table (i assume you insert the id to another table and that the id is the primary key). This will lock this record. Any other transaction trying to insert the same key into the table will block/fail.

Answer (score 1):

We have an utility class that implements roughly what you describe in experiment 2:

Prerequisite: having a dedicated table for the lock

On lock phase, a new connection is created; a INSERT INTO is performed on the lock table.

On unlock phase, a rollback on the connection is performed regardless of the execution of the business logic.

It is used like a java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock:

```
Lock lock = new Lock(...);
lock.lock();
try {

    // your business logic
} finally {
   lock.unlock();
}
```

It works on websphere / oracle.

Note that if you use JPA, there is a built-in support for entity locking.

Comment: This is a perfect working example. Here your code controls the entire workflow. But in our case it is the spring integration framework. Multiple instances of the consumers reside in different weblogic nodes(1 per node). I can commit the changes to the temporary table before the message is processed. I can also release the lock post processing. But if there is an exception in the message processing, then the lock is going to get stuck(I dont have a callback in exception case). So I should be writing some dirty logic based on the age of the lock before message processing. This is my problem

Comment: Would it be possible to manage the lock at the consumer side? If consumers are MDB, an interceptor could manage the lock; it will keep your business logic clean.

Comment: My objective is to keep a message from being delivered to more than 1 consumer. If the consumer handles aborting as an exception case is my only way out which is not elegant.